# По какой причине, драйвере HD Audio, может исчезнуть звук при подключении колонок?

Tags: windows, драйвер

Были сверены хеш суммы с диском оригинала, и в дир \DriversStore, диретории начинающиеся с HD Audio, хеш суммы файлов всех совпадали. А параметры реестра не отличаются. В то время драйвер reltek  работает колонки (подключенные по джеку).

Comment: Качать свежие с сайта реалтека пробовал?

Comment: Перестали работать родные, при этом переустановка системы (например рядом) не помогает. А изначально из этого дистрибутива родные работали. Прям атакует искуственный интеллект.
не бывает же аппаратных изменений, если на линуксе работает. Реалтек не интересует, это троянский конь с изображением рачка, если иконки не заменить

Comment: `А изначально из этого дистрибутива родные работали.` - винда легко может подтянуть обновы сразу после установки ОС. Так что один и тот же iso не гарантирует 100% повторяемости. Ну или надо рубить инет. `это троянский конь` - с этого места по-подробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: Официально винда не скачивала никаких обновлений. Высшие силы заменили файлы на моем диске и н авсех образах планеты..

Comment: Ещё идея. Или бывают такие "вирусы" загрузчик модифицируют, и спецом звук именно на внешние динамики отключают, ничего не вымогая явно. Именно на все системах которые загрузятся через загрузчик, и антивирус не находит изменений в ОЗУ, но говорит про загрузчик и не лечит др. веб.

Comment: `Реалтек не интересует, это троянский конь` после этой фразы оставленной без подкреплённой инфы доказывающей это - тебе тут вряд ли кто поможет. `"вирусы" загрузчик модифицируют` - точно не помогут.